# PIXI JS Priority call mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pixi.js

When we create multiple sprites, the function **mouseover** is called when **any hover** in hitArea polygon. Regardless, whether applied to another object.

Visibility of sprite governed by sorting the array. The later was added to the sprite in stage.children, the higher it will be. Here is an example in which one rectangle superimposed on the other. At the same time, when we put things on the upper left corner of the bottom sprite, at the top of the object function mouseover will work call, although it is under the other.

How to solve this problem? hitarea not suitable, since the facilities will be constantly dragging.

Thanks in advance for your reply!

```
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x97c56e, true);
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth,         window.innerHeight, null);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
renderer.view.style.top = "0px";
renderer.view.style.left = "0px";
requestAnimFrame( animate );

var texture = new PIXI.RenderTexture()
r1 = new PIXI.Graphics()
r1.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
r1.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
r1.endFill()
texture.render(r1);

var texture2 = new PIXI.RenderTexture()
r1 = new PIXI.Graphics()
r1.beginFill(0xDDDD00);
r1.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
r1.endFill()
texture2.render(r1);

createBunny(100, 100, texture)
createBunny(120, 120, texture2)

function createBunny(x, y, texture) {

    var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
    bunny.interactive = true;
    bunny.buttonMode = true;
    bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
    bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;

    bunny.scale.x = bunny.scale.y = 0.5;

    bunny.mouseover = function(data) {
        console.log('mouse over!')
    }

    bunny.mousedown = bunny.touchstart = function(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.alpha = 0.9;
        this.dragging = true;
        this.sx = this.data.getLocalPosition(bunny).x * bunny.scale.x;
        this.sy = this.data.getLocalPosition(bunny).y * bunny.scale.y;      
    };

    bunny.mouseup = bunny.mouseupoutside = bunny.touchend = bunny.touchendoutside = function(data) {
        this.alpha = 1
        this.dragging = false;
        this.data = null;
    };

    bunny.mousemove = bunny.touchmove = function(data) {
        if(this.dragging) {
            var newPosition = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
            this.position.x = newPosition.x - this.sx;
            this.position.y = newPosition.y - this.sy;
        }
    }

    bunny.position.x = x;
    bunny.position.y = y;

    stage.addChild(bunny);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame( animate );
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sD8Tt/48/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old thread, but for those who come to this page, the issue can be fixed by extending the PIXI's Sprite Class, Look at the following code.

```
PIXI.Sprite.prototype.bringToFront = function() {
    if (this.parent) {
        var parent = this.parent;
        parent.removeChild(this);
        parent.addChild(this);
    }
}
```

And call above method in mousedown event like this

```
this.bringToFront();
```

Working JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6rk58cqa/